# How can I encrypt data in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

I have a PHP file which allows users to insert text into the MySql database. I want that data to be encrypted. (Any encryption would be ok for me... MD5, SHA1, SHA512, any of them) And when the user requests the data from the database, it is shown as regular plain text (The value entered by him). Please help me how can I do it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

MD5, SHA1 and SHA512 are hash-functions, no reversible encryption.

I would recommend to use the encryption/decryption pair [AES_ENCRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) and [AES_DECRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt).

Answer (score 1):

MD5, SHA1, SHA512 are hashing and compression tools, so it is impossible to *decrypt* text that is *cloaked* by these algorithms (check the [difference between hashing and encryption](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/)).
These 2 PHP functions could suit your needs for this specific case: you case use this function to [encrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and this one to [decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have seen many PHP login scripts which use MD5 for hashing their passwords stored in their database. So how is it decrypted if it is impossible to decrypt them by these algorithms?

Comment: @user3668837 Passwords encrypted simply with `MD5`, `SHA1` ... are stored encrypted and never got back in plain text. The 2 functions for encrypting and decrypting allows use to use a list of encryption algorithms you can find [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php). And remember that MD5 is a hash function, so no way to decrypt its result. You must check the link i gave you through my answer to see the difference between encryption and hashing which are totally different. If my answer hels you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

On user registration, concatenate login name and password chosen by him/her with a salt value, hash the concatenation with PHP **$PwdHash=md5($salt.$loginname.$password);** and store $PwdHash in database.

When the user wants to autenticate later, he/she sends the $loginname and $password again. 
Repeat the same with obtained credentials **$PwdHash=md5($salt.$loginname.$password);** and compare computed $PwdHash with PwdHash stored in your database row corresponding to $loginname.

Salt is an arbitrary constant secret value chosen by you, e.g. **$salt="user3668837";** . Using the salt prevents the attacker to dig out passwords from your database with *rainbow tables* if he managed to steal database content.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually I want the data entered to be decrypted when the user requests it. The data should be displayed on the screen as it was entered by the user.. And  md5 can not be decrypted....